# Coffeescript - How to invoke a method two levels up the scope chain?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

How does one invoke a function that is two levels up the scope chain, like `_write_colors_data_to_file` in this example:

```
class Server
  _sio_configure_listener: (app) ->

    sio = Socket.listen app,
      'logger'   : logger,
      'log level': logger.level

    # when Client user runs `io.connect()`
    sio.sockets.on 'connection', (socket) ->

      # when Client is live-previewing color
      socket.on 'colorChanged', (data) ->
        logger.info 'colorChanged event emitted'

        # how do I invoke this method?
        @_write_colors_data_to_file()

  _write_colors_data_to_file: ->
    # some logic

module.exports = Server
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd avoid two levels of `=>` for this, that smears your context all over the place and makes things a bit too confusing for my taste. I'd use a named function (or at least CoffeeScript's version of a named function):

```
_sio_configure_listener: (app) ->
  #...
  save_colors = (data) =>
    logger.info 'colorChanged event emitted'
    @_write_colors_data_to_file()
  sio.sockets.on 'connection', (socket) ->
    socket.on 'colorChanged', save_colors
```

That keeps the [binding `=>`](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow) close to the `@` you're binding to and later, when you bind to the `'colorChanged'` event, you just have a simple piece of logic conveniently named `save_colors`.

Just because you can use anonymous functions all over the place doesn't mean you have to.

Comment: Nice answer, I agree that avoiding two levels of `=>` can reduce confusion and complexity here.

Would you ever recommend preserving the `this` context and referencing it later like, `_this = this` in coffeescript?

Comment: I'd only use the `_this = @` trick in CoffeeScript if I needed both the current `@` and the one that a callback would normally get. I think I've only done that once though. I've actually been moving away from anonymous functions (unless they're one-liners) for the most part, attaching names to your little packets of logic makes things much easier to understand. `_this = this` also has the same action-at-a-distance problems that make nested bound functions a bit confusing and difficult to keep track of.

Answer (score 3):

You can use fat arrow (=>) notation to bind the callbacks you are passing to socket.io to the current `this`.  That way, `@` will refer to your `Server` instance.

See [this section](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow) of the CoffeeScript docs for more info.

```
class Server
  _sio_configure_listener: (app) ->

    sio = Socket.listen app,
      'logger'   : logger,
      'log level': logger.level

    # when Client user runs `io.connect()`
    sio.sockets.on 'connection', (socket) =>

      # when Client is live-previewing color
      socket.on 'colorChanged', (data) =>
        logger.info 'colorChanged event emitted'

        # how do I invoke this method?
        @_write_colors_data_to_file()

  _write_colors_data_to_file: ->
    # some logic

module.exports = Server
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Server
  _sio_configure_listener: (app) ->

    self = @
    sio = Socket.listen app,
      'logger'   : logger,
      'log level': logger.level

    # when Client user runs `io.connect()`
    sio.sockets.on 'connection', (socket) ->

      # when Client is live-previewing color
      socket.on 'colorChanged', (data) ->
        logger.info 'colorChanged event emitted'

        # how do I invoke this method?
        self._write_colors_data_to_file()

  _write_colors_data_to_file: ->
    # some logic

module.exports = Server
```

Comment: There is no `self` in coffeescript...?